# Is there a reliable way to detect the country of the user in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, internationalization, progressive-web-apps, e-commerce

We are building a PWA using vanilla JS, CSS and HTML on the client. We need our online store (HTML/CSS/JS) to show prices based on country. The backend will be nodeJS/Express. We have a couple of products listed and need to display prices based on the country of the user. What are the options to precisely determine which country is the user visiting from?

To be honest, we have not tried many options yet as it is difficult to test. But a preliminary reading on the topic suggests that the browser's geolocation API alone might not be sufficient.

Comment: Keep it simple. Just simple IP check (a lot of libraries have good data of them). In any case you must allow user to change country and currency.

Comment: I should have written 'any' @JaromandaX, as you suggested. Looking for guidance here.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Is there any other reason to allow the user to change country/currency except the possibility that we might not guess the country correctly?

Comment: @Rahul: the most annoying thing is to fight believes of a computer (world is too complex for computers and for programmers, we still fail a lot). There will be bugs, special cases, and people traveling (you may want to order an item on the travel back from your holidays). Mobile phones may be tricky. Corporations may use IP of different countries (or better: IP databases are not accurate: especially if the network registration is done on a different country). Etc. Real world is never simple.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you for your inputs and feedback. I see your point. The concern we are grappling with is that the products we sell are mostly digital - online programs and consultations, so providing an option to change the country themselves, might give in to the clever user behavior to just choose the lowest prices from the options and check out.

Comment: People have VPN. Some sites use country of issue of the credit card to forbid such price country shopping. OTOH for such kind of services possibly one would not change country (and for few cases you give wrong prices, but it is a trade-off you should decide)

Comment: I'm traveling around a lot, and not having the ability to change the currency on some website is one of the worst user experience. For example I'm right now in Japan, and I want to be able to switch prices in EUR. If I can't (which is often the case), I just close that website and try an other one...